# Forever pending

Tags: gnosis-safe

I've tried Gnosis Safe in Rinkeby environment, but when there is a transaction revert like this(https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xeb7ac58246fe120db8b86f6cda244edcb011292d9ddb916b15b2d2516d218870), it shows forever pending status. How can I exit this status? I tried to clear the cookie clearing but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting the bug. We'll look into this.

For the time being, if you close/reopen your browser, the status will clear. Alternatively, you can clear your session storage via the console with the `sessionStorage.clear()` command.

If you can provide any more information regarding the issue, e.g. the browser and wallet used, please add them to [this issue](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/3440) created.

Comment: thank you. I have used both metamask and ledger

Comment: Also, it sometimes fails when canceling the tx or when confirming batching the tx confirmation and execution. do you know why?

Comment: I'm sorry you're encountering further problems. If I understand correctly, you are encountering a different issue.

Can you please create a new question with as much detail as possible, including the Ledger model and firmware. Alternatively, you can report the bug as an issue on [our GitHub](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues) and we'll look into it for you.